# Regarding chrome fullscreen message disable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to disable fullscreen message ("you've gone fullscreen") coming on the top when chrome fullscreen mode is activated .

i need to do it through javascript . but it's one of the default functionality of chrome.

can any one help me out ?

Comment: You can't it's there for security.

Comment: If you only need it for yourself have a look at [this page](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. As you pointed you **it's one of the default functionality of chrome**.

and I agree with the comment by mic **You can't it's there for security**

Answer (score 0):

That message is, if you it can be disabled at all, likely a user preference. I have had my fair share of changing that kind of things for a custom "layer" over windows with an integrated browser and I can tell you it's impossible with javascript without some listener app. We created a C# listener app for that kind of thing that keeps checking a certain text file. We made javascript edit the text file and then let C# work it's hacking magic in some of the user's settings.

You could take a look at [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/), the stripped down version of Chrome, if that would be of any help ;)

ps: To all the people going mental over changing user settings like that, our customers were old people that were unable to use a computer, and our application's purpose was to do as much as possible for them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot possibly do that as suggested by these links.

https://superuser.com/questions/398945/disable-the-youve-gone-full-screen-notification-in-chrome

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/h1crbhOy-7U

On the other note, why exactly would you want to do that?